# About using jinja templating in JS file

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I have been using a template in which there's images of previous and next button is in JavaScript file. The Framework I'm using is Django, is there any solution to use jinja templating/rendering for these images in JS file.

JS code:

```
$(".active-banner-slider").owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        autoplay:false,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        loop:true,
        nav:true,
        navText:["<img src={% static 'img/banner/prev.png' >","<img src={% static 'img/banner/next.png' %}>"],
        dots:false
    });
```

I used same static method with html files and it worked, I don't know if this method does even work with JS file or not? if it does what would be the correct way?

Comment: jinja is used for `html` files not `js` files, although this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404129/how-to-access-external-javascript-files-through-jinjaflask) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can generate a JS component of a web page using the Django template processor, or Jinja if you prefer. You do, however, need to make sure that the JS is generated in the correct context (surrounded by appropriate tags, in the right place in your rendered output). You also have to be careful to code your JS using `{ {` and `} }` (significant spaces!) never  `{{`.

If you use "view page source" and your browser's debugging tools, you will probably spot what you are doing wrong.

My site base template has a block `onready_js` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(  function() {
{% block onready_js %}{% endblock onready_js %}   
   }); 
</script>
```

into which you can inject bits of JS to be executed when the page becomes ready, like this (ignore the irrelevant details, apart from the use of `{{...}}` and `{% if ... %}`  etc. Absent any block  definition, the base template generates a null `$(document).ready(  function() { });`

```
{% block onready_js %}

{% if form or POST_name %} 
  // activate the button column to POST to this target with this name
  var buttons = $('button.MyFilterSelectButton');
  buttons.attr('type','submit').attr('name','{{POST_name}}')
  buttons.click( function(event){ 
  $('#id_{{POST_name}}').val( $(this).attr('value') );
    /* stuff deleted */
  $('.MyFilterSelectCol').show();

{% else %}
  // hide the button column which doesn't do anything useful
  $('.MyFilterSelectCol').hide();
{% endif %}

{% endblock onready_js %}
```

Comment: Yes!!  I got the strike, I just needed to move a particular code into my html file and then do the same method and it worked..!!