# How to display generator contents using a Jinja Python template

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, generator

I created a Python generator using the Flask framework to generate a list of product SKUs and their stock status (either "in stock" or "out of stock"), and display them using the Python Jinja template. The code for the generator function `generateStockStatus()` is shown below:

```python
def generateStockStatus():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    if request_data:
        if 'SKU' in request_data:
            stockRequest = request_data['SKU'] # List of product SKUs sent in the request
            for stock in stockRequest:
                if stock in stockList:
                    stockStatus = "in stock"
                    stockSheet.update({str(stock):stockStatus})
                else:
                    stockStatus = "out of stock"
                    stockSheet.update({str(stock):stockStatus})

                yield str(stock)
                yield stockStatus
```

The generator function is wrapped inside the view function `sendStockStatus()` in the `tasks_consumer.py` file.

```python
@app.route('/consumetasks', methods=['POST'])
def sendStockStatus():
    stockList = [] # List of products in stock
    with open("NZ_NVJ_Apparel_SKUs_sheet.csv", newline='') as csvFile:
        stockReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in stockReader:
            stockList.append(row[0])
    
    stockSheet = {} # Dictionary of products sent in the request and their stock status

    def generateStockStatus():
        ...
                        
    return stream_with_context(generateStockStatus())
```

The Jinja template to be rendered, which is `consumer.html`, is rendered using another view function `getStockStatus()` in the `app_consumer.py` file:

```python
@app.route('/consumetasks', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getStockStatus():
    # Handle the POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Retrieving stock status")
        return Response(render_template_stream('consumer.html', stockInfo = tasks_consumer.sendStockStatus()))     
    # Handle the GET request
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        ...
```

The function `render_template_stream()` renders a template with a given context as a stream and return a TemplateStream. Its function definition is shown below:

```python
def render_template_stream(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv
```

I tried to use the `consumer.html` Jinja template to display the product SKUs and their stock status. The variable `stockInfo` is passed to the template as a context. It is a generator object storing a list of strings, where the product SKUs and their corresponding stock statuses appear one after another. Relevant part of the template is shown below.

```html
<div id="stockSheet"> </div>
{% for stock in stockInfo %}
  {% if loop.index0 is even %}
    <script>
      var SKU = "{{stock}}";
      document.getElementById("stockSheet").innerHTML += ("Product" + SKU);
    </script>
  {% elif loop.index0 is odd %}
    <script>
      var stockStatus = "{{stock}}";
      document.getElementById("stockSheet").innerHTML += ("is" + stockStatus + "<br>");
    </script>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, after I ran the relevant Python files and launched the server, no contents were displayed inside the `<div id="stockSheet">` element in the rendered template. What should I do in order to successfully display words like `Product TSHIRT_CN_US_CLS_M_OLIVEDRAB is in stock` on the rendered template?

Answer (score 0):

Since the generator function is being called only with a POST request, please make sure that you're not expecting the data to be displayed when you initially fetch the page which is a GET request.
Regardless of whether it's a GET or POST request, you don't need to use the custom `render_template_stream` unless it serves a very specific use in your application since Flask already has the built-in `stream_template` function that achieves the same result. (See [the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/streaming/))

Since I don't have the exact data you're working with, here's a working example of what you might be hoping to achieve:

```py
@app.route("/generator")
def generator_to_template():
    # list of objects to mimic stock data
    stock_data = []
    
    def generate_data():
        for single in stock_data:
            if single.get("productID") % 3 == 0:
                stockStatus = "Out of Stock"
            else:
                stockStatus = "In Stock"
            
            yield str(single.get("SKU"))
            yield stockStatus

    return stream_template("stock_sheet.html", stockInfo=generate_data())
```

Your template:

```html
<body>
        <div id="stockSheet"> </div>
        <!-- Only one <script> tag is needed. -->
        <script>
            {% for stock in stockInfo %}
                {% if loop.index0 is even %}
                    var SKU = "{{stock}}";
                    document.getElementById("stockSheet").innerHTML += ("Product " + SKU);
                {% elif loop.index0 is odd %}
                    var stockStatus = "{{stock}}";
                    document.getElementById("stockSheet").innerHTML += (" is " + stockStatus + "<br>");
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I access the generator URL:

[image: Result after accessing the generator endpoint]

This is what the generated JavaScript looks like:

[image: JavaScript generated by the for loop]

Comment: Firstly, you can't put Jinja statements like `{% for stock in stockInfo %}` inside a `<script>` tag because a `<script>` tag is supposed to contain JavaScript statements and Jinja statements won't be recognised inside the tag. Secondly, I have added the function definition for `render_template_stream()` to the question. Please have a look and reconsider whether the built-in Flask function `stream_template()` will achieve the same result.

Comment: You can add Jinja statements/filters inside the `<script>` tag. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/crawftv/ab93a72ff0d0ba53eafd2a7cde601fab#file-javascript-jinja-html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68286442). The working code I included also shows this. I've updated my answer to include a screenshot of the generated JavaScript.
`render_template_stream` seems to make context data available for the template to use. `stream_template` allows you to pass the context. See [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.stream_template).